# Monkey patching a @property

Tags: python, python-3.x, monkeypatching

Is it at all possible to monkey patch the value of a `@property` of an instance of a class that I do not control?

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return here().be['dragons']

f = Foo()
print(f.bar)  # baz
f.bar = 42    # MAGIC!
print(f.bar)  # 42
```

Obviously the above would produce an error when trying to assign to `f.bar`. Is `# MAGIC!` possible in any way? The implementation details of the `@property` are a black box and not indirectly monkey-patchable. The entire method call needs to be replaced. It needs to affect a single instance only (class-level patching is okay if inevitable, but the changed behaviour must only selectively affect a given instance, not all instances of that class).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make `f.bar` not a property any more (and if so, without affecting other instances?) Note that properties, like other descriptors, are stored *on the class*.

Comment: Yes, I want to affect the value which is returned when accessing `f.bar` on this one instance only.

Comment: I think the only way to do that would be to alter `f.__dict__` directly, providing a new `bar` attribute that will get looked up before the property is, but only for that single instance.

Comment: I had tried that, but the property always seems to get looked up first. A working example would be good...

Comment: I had the wrong interpreter open; that only works on old-style classes. Consider me embarrassed.

Comment: `Foo.bar = 42` ... or you just want to change the property of an instance?

Comment: @LittleQ As discussed above, just one instance.

Comment: My solution was to make copy of the class, change the descriptor and then replace the instance's class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30578922/248296

Comment: why not use a subclass of `Foo`? @deceze

Comment: @LittleQ Because I'm getting an instance of `Foo` from somewhere and I do not control its instantiation. I also have to work with *this* instance of the object, as it reflects back to others who hold a reference to it.

Comment: @deceze You can change the class using `Foo().__class__ = SubFoo`

Comment: @Markus Care to expand that into an answer? Sounds like that might be the best approach.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Subclass the base class (`Foo`) and change single instance's class to match the new subclass using `__class__` attribute:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @property
...     def bar(self):
...         return 'Foo.bar'
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar
'Foo.bar'
>>> class _SubFoo(Foo):
...     bar = 0
...
>>> f.__class__ = _SubFoo
>>> f.bar
0
>>> f.bar = 42
>>> f.bar
42
```

Comment: Sounds like a winner!

Comment: Will it be better if replace `bar = 0` with `bar = f.bar` in `_SubFoo` declaration to keep previous value of `f.bar`?

Comment: @f43d65 If the subclass is used for one instance only, then sure. You can even set the bar directly to `42` if that's the value you want anyways. But if multiple instances need to use the same class (in order to override the same attribute), you're better off giving it a simple default value like `0`.

Answer (score 27):

```
from module import ClassToPatch

def get_foo(self):
    return 'foo'

setattr(ClassToPatch, 'foo', property(get_foo))
```

Comment: Perfect!  I used this to patch the base class for a framework to support a much needed feature.  By far the easiest way to do it, though I do think the description in here could be a little better :)  If you know your .py then just the bit of code makes enough sense.

Comment: @kzh: Can we also reuse the original `foo` property? I tried `old_foo = ClassToPatch.foo` followed by `return old_foo` without success

Comment: That doesn't work for a property setter.

Comment: @Konstantin what have you tried to enable the setter?

Answer (score 15):

To monkey patch a property, there is an even simpler way:

```
from module import ClassToPatch

def get_foo(self):
    return 'foo'

ClassToPatch.foo = property(get_foo)
```

Comment: The question was how to overwrite an existing property.  This answer has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment? In my understanding, it will indeed overwite an existing property (the question was not about subclassing but monkey patching).

Comment: Sorry, my comment was vague and based on me misinterpreting your answer.  I was thinking you were doing `instance.foo = ...`, which would fail if `foo` were actually an existing property of that class, but you actually wrote `class.foo = ...`, which works just fine.  So I was wrong.  However, while we're at it, there are two other issues: 1) the questioner was looking to patch an instance, not a class, and 2) they were looking to patch it with a static value, not another property.  Regardless, I think your answer still adds some value as is.

Comment: Intuitive implementation and works like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Idea: replace property descriptor to allow setting on certain objects. Unless a value is explicitly set this way, original property getter is called.

The problem is how to store the explicitly set values. We cannot use a `dict` keyed by patched objects, since 1) they are not necessarily comparable by identity; 2) this prevents patched objects from being garbage-collected. For 1) we could write a `Handle` that wraps objects and overrides comparison semantics by identity and for 2) we could use `weakref.WeakKeyDictionary`. However, I couldn't make these two work together.

Therefore we use a different approach of storing the explicitly set values on the object itself, using a "very unlikely attribute name". It is of course still possible that this name would collide with something, but that's pretty much inherent to languages such as Python.

This won't work on objects that lack a `__dict__` slot. Similar problem would arise for weakrefs though.

```
class Foo:
    @property
    def bar (self):
        return 'original'

class Handle:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._obj is other._obj

    def __hash__(self):
        return id (self._obj)


_monkey_patch_index = 0
_not_set            = object ()
def monkey_patch (prop):
    global _monkey_patch_index, _not_set
    special_attr = '$_prop_monkey_patch_{}'.format (_monkey_patch_index)
    _monkey_patch_index += 1

    def getter (self):
        value = getattr (self, special_attr, _not_set)
        return prop.fget (self) if value is _not_set else value

    def setter (self, value):
        setattr (self, special_attr, value)

    return property (getter, setter)

Foo.bar = monkey_patch (Foo.bar)

f = Foo()
print (Foo.bar.fset)
print(f.bar)  # baz
f.bar = 42    # MAGIC!
print(f.bar)  # 42
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Essentially, the class needs to be patched, just the instance can't be?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to move on from properties to the realms of data descriptors and non-data descriptors. Properties are just a specialised version of data descriptors. Functions are an example of non-data descriptors -- when you retrieve them from an instance they return a method rather than the function itself.

A non-data descriptor is just an instance of a class that has a `__get__` method. The only difference with a data descriptor is that it has a `__set__` method as well. Properties initially have a `__set__` method that throws an error unless you provide a setter function.

You can achieve what you want really easily just by writing your own trivial non-data descriptor.

```
class nondatadescriptor:
    """generic nondata descriptor decorator to replace @property with"""
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __get__(self, obj, objclass):
        if obj is not None:
            # instance based access
            return self.func(obj)
        else:
            # class based access
            return self

class Foo:
    @nondatadescriptor
    def bar(self):
        return "baz"

foo = Foo()
another_foo = Foo()

assert foo.bar == "baz"
foo.bar = 42
assert foo.bar == 42
assert another_foo.bar == "baz"
del foo.bar
assert foo.bar == "baz"
print(Foo.bar)
```

What makes all this work is that logic under the hood `__getattribute__`. I can't find the appropriate documentation at the moment, but order of retrieval is:

1. Data descriptors defined on the class are given the highest priority (objects with both `__get__` and `__set__`), and their `__get__` method is invoked.
2. Any attribute of the object itself.
3. Non-data descriptors defined on the class (objects with only a `__get__` method).
4. All other attributes defined on the class.
5. Finally the `__getattr__` method of the object is invoked as a last resort (if defined).

Comment: That's nice and all, but I'm really trying to duck punch a 3rd party library here. ;)

Comment: You can just monkey patch the class property then. eg. `Foo.bar = nondatadescriptor(Foo.bar.fget)`. All other property access remain the same, but you can now set `foo.bar`.

Comment: Sure, but I'd probably do it slightly differently. He goes to a lot of effort to find somewhere to place the new value. But due to the semantics of  `__getattribute__`, `foo.__dict__["bar"]` is the perfect hiding spot. Unless of the course `Foo` does some funky stuff with the instance's `__dict__`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also patch property setters. Using @fralau 's answer:

```py
from module import ClassToPatch

def foo(self, new_foo):
    self._foo = new_foo

ClassToPatch.foo = ClassToPatch.foo.setter(foo)
```

[reference](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/895#issuecomment-515025300)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs to patch a property while being able to call the original implementation, here is an example:

```
@property
def _cursor_args(self, __orig=mongoengine.queryset.base.BaseQuerySet._cursor_args):
    # TODO: remove this hack when we upgrade MongoEngine
    # https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/pull/2160
    cursor_args = __orig.__get__(self)
    if self._timeout:
        cursor_args.pop("no_cursor_timeout", None)
    return cursor_args


mongoengine.queryset.base.BaseQuerySet._cursor_args = _cursor_args
```